# Can I change the date format only in the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, date-time

Can I change the display format just for the date in the windows taskbar?
I know that you can customize the format of the date in the taskbar by changing the "short date" display format in region/language settings, but that has broader effects that I want to avoid. Is there a way to just override those settings in this context or tell the taskbar to not use the region's date formatting?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to persuade the built in date display in the notification area to use anything other than the active short date format.

There are third party replacement date/time notification widgets that give you such customization options. But not for the built in widget.

Comment: Can you help identify such a widget? I thought the same but didn't know the right search terms to find one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on that